# firefox addons only display in safe mode

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Simply my addons won't display in 'normal' mode and i will have to boot up in safe mode to view my addons and add them disable them etc.

This is rather frustrating. I don't want to start over with Firefox either. I have a rather large amount of bespoke settings, not just addson running.

I removed All in one sidebar and now i do see a permanent loading when i enter the addons tab.

```
safe mode -> addons displayed
Normal -> just a perm loading sign
```

Comment: You should try disabling some of your add-ons (yes, in safe mode), one of them is responsible for this. Btw, I flagged this question as off-topic - it belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: thanks, n ye i used safe mode. In the end i couldn't work out why this was happening. So i just uninstalled 1 by 1 until i got rid of the evil addon :)

Comment: Please tell us which one it was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end i just removed each addon until after my reset i had my addons displaying again.

I reinstalled the addon after a reset of firefox.